# How to launch flameshot screencapture with prtscr on i3

Tags: debian, i3

So I've just installed flameshot, and when I launch it, it appears in applets section of UI. However, I must click it to run the screen capture. Can I somehow make PrtScr a shortcut for flameshot screen capture? I'm using i3.

Answer (score 7):

You can execute it using `i3-dmenu-desktop`.

Just bind it to a key in your i3 config

```
bindsym $mod+[any key] exec i3-dmenu-desktop
```

Then you can launch any desktop apps from there.

---

Or if you want to bind flameshot to <kbd>Prt Sc</kbd> key

```
bindsym Print exec /path/to/flameshot
```

Or if you want to launch flameshot gui instead of spawning it in tray:

```
bindsym Print exec "flameshot gui"
```

Answer (score 0):

i3's `bindsym` directive can be used to bind a key or set of keys/strokes to commands.  i3's `exec` command will execute programs and start processes.

Add to your i3 config (`$HOME/.config/i3/config`) and reload the configuration or restart i3:

```
echo 'bindsym Print exec flameshot' >> $HOME/.config/i3/config
i3-msg reload
```

On my system, with `Alt` as my modifier key (`$mod`), combining `Alt + Print` actually issues `Sys_Req`.  You'll need to modify your binding accordingly if you want this to work:

```
echo 'bindsym $mod+Sys_Req ...'
```